# Multiple TVs and single NAS

Tags: samsung-smart-tv, television, nas

I have QNAP NAS (TS-431XeU) and 8 SAMSUNG TVs (ue43nu7192u) and I would like to connect them via LAN and play media files from NAS.

A single connection is OK, I just plug in ethernet to TV and setup it, this is fine.

But I would like to connect 4 TV together to create one big screen, is there any way how to achieve this? 
With the possibility to use them separately and connect them together to act like one if needed?

Comment: I reccomend asking this in https://diy.stackexchange.com/ I had to flag this because it is off topic, Stackoverflow answers questions related to code, mainly js, html, css, python, C#, C++ and others.

Comment: Hi Taylor, ok, understood, sorry for this mistake made by me

Comment: Its alright, everyone makes mistakes, I'm one to talk considering I put my rigid body physics question in Superuser rather than stackoverflow

Comment: Hi Taylor, I posted my Q to diy section and I got deleted, because "This question does not appear to be about home improvement within the scope defined in the help center", so I am confused now where should I ask...:(

Comment: Well Im not sure, It really depends on the question, Superuser has TV related questions about shortcuts, stack has TV Code questions, theres even TV related questions in Mathematics Stackexchange, youd have to contact a moderator for a bit more insight. Im retracting my flag for this question as Im not quite sure if it really belongs here or not, Apologies *facepalm*

Comment: I understand your confusion here because I am confused too :D

Comment: @FilipNiko I do not use this model specifically but there is no way to do this on the models I do use without additional hardware and software.

Comment: @erisco Could you recommend me some SW and HW, please? :)